# PHP - Get PDF standard, isoname, cmyk metadata

Tags: php, pdf, metadata, tcpdf, imagick

my goal is to get additional pdf metadata like standard, isoname, cmyk...

I already tried TCPDF, Imagick, GD and other libs without success.
Imagick has the method "getColorspace" but unfortunately that one does not work properly with pdfs as in pdfs we have to view every layer?

```
function check_image_is_cmyk($image_file_path) {
    $imagick_file_contents = file_get_contents($image_file_path);
    $imagick_file = new Imagick();
    $imagick_file->readImageBlob($imagick_file_contents);
    $image_color_space = $imagick_file->getimagecolorspace();

    /* BEGIN - ALL AVAILABLE COLORSPACE CONSTANTS
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_UNDEFINED; //0
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB; //1
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY; //2
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_TRANSPARENT; //3
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_OHTA; //4
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_LAB; //5
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_XYZ; //6
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_YCBCR; //7
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_YCC; //8
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_YIQ; //9
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_YPBPR; //10
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_YUV; //11
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK; //12
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB; //13
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_HSB; //14
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_HSL; //15
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_HWB; //16
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_REC601LUMA; //17
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_REC601YCBCR; //18
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_REC709LUMA; //19
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_REC709YCBCR; //20
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_LOG; //21
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMY; //22
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_LUV; //23
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_HCL; //24
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_LCH; //25
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_LMS; //26
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_LCHAB; //27
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_LCHUV; //28
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_SCRGB; //29
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_HSI; //30
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_HSV; //31
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_HCLP; //32
      Imagick::COLORSPACE_YDBDR; //33
      END - ALL AVAILABLE COLORSPACE CONSTANTS */

    if ($image_color_space === Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is how I already get the PDF version but unfortunately not the standard (e.g. PDF/X-3)

```
function check_pdf_version($image_file_path) {
    $imagick_file_contents = file_get_contents($image_file_path);
    $imagick_file = new Imagick();
    $imagick_file->readImageBlob($imagick_file_contents);

    $exif_array = $imagick_file->getImageProperties();

    $pdf_version = "";

    if (!empty($exif_array['pdf:Version'])) {
        $pdf_version = str_replace('PDF-', "", $exif_array['pdf:Version']);
    }

    if (!empty($exif_array['pdf:Version']) && floatval($pdf_version) > 1.2) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example:
If I open up a pdf file I can get these infos:

[image]

Anyone has an idea how I could extract these additional data.

Comment: Everything you need to know is here: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf For instance, the "Standard" and "ISO" info are in the XMP Metadata. The "Quark Generic" may be in the Info dictionary, or the XMP also, not sure what that application is checking/showing. A big issue with your question is that a single PDF page can contain many color spaces. There is no one color space.  If you are NOT looking for a general solution, and are just interested in analyzing a specific (set) of PDF file(s) then post samples here.

Comment: A big issue with your question is that a single PDF page can contain many color spaces - that's exactly the problem and I want to check every available colorspace if it is cmyk or not - also the Info Dictionary or the XMP -> is it even possible to get these values with PHP? Thanks

Comment: "that's exactly the problem and I want to check every available colorspace if it is cmyk or not" - Then you need to parse the page content streams, and check ever image resource. "also the Info Dictionary or the XMP -> is it even possible to get these values with PHP?" - Sure, that is definitely the easiest part of your question. I think you need to pick a PHP PDF library first, and then update your question with what you tried. Right now your question appears to be a software recommendation question which is not really allowed.